# How can I make a typescript type where all keys in object have same prefix?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to create a object type `UiPrefixed` where all the keys in the object have to be prefixed with `/^ui\:.+/`, is this possible?

```
type UiPrefixed = {
  [`ui:*`]: any
}

const e: UiPrefixed = {
  'ui:meow': true,
  'ui:woof': true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is one of the scenarios where [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) can come in handy: `ui:${string}`:

```ts
type UiPrefixed = {
  [key: `ui:${string}`]: any
}

const e: UiPrefixed = {
  'ui:meow': true,
  'ui:woof': true
}
```

See proof-of-concept on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqglgBQE4QGZwB4QCZQLxQDeAUFFANoDWEIAXFAAYCuctAJIQM7BJwB2AcwC+DALr0AhnxDEhxYgGMA9n25QI9eMjSYc+IqSgByFrQC2EJQHcj9HkwgAaQydZWlS1Laj2IsoA).

Comment: These aren't really "literal types" of the sort mentioned in the doc you linked to.  They are *pattern template literal* types, and can be used in index signatures [since TS4.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures); you might want to update the doc link.